# gitlab ci/cd Uploading artifacts as "junit" to coordinator... failed 500

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to test gitlab ci/cd with a simple `helloWorld` project of one main class and one test class, build with `ant`, but when I run the pipeline it gives me this error :

```
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "junit" to coordinator... failed  id=13076195 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=fxB2Np58
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "junit" to coordinator... failed  id=13076195 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=fxB2Np58
WARNING: Retrying...                                context=artifacts-uploader error=invalid argument
WARNING: Uploading artifacts as "junit" to coordinator... failed  id=13076195 responseStatus=500 Internal Server Error status=500 token=fxB2Np58 FATAL: invalid argument                             Cleaning up file based variables 00:00 ERROR: Job failed: command terminated with exit code 1
```

here is my `gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: java:latest
     
stages:
  - test

test-stage:    
  image: frekele/ant    
  stage: test   
  script:
    - echo starting tests
    - ant junit
  artifacts:     
    paths: 
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/build/junitreport
    reports: 
      junit: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/build/junitreport
  when: always
```

Comment: How does you pipeline look like?

Comment: could you show your `gitlab-ci.yml` ?

Comment: image: java:latest

stages:
    - test

test-stage:
  image: frekele/ant
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo starting tests
    - ant junit

  artifacts:
    paths: 
      - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/build/junitreport
    when: always
    reports: 
      junit:  $CI_PROJECT_DIR/build/junitreport

Comment: @danielnelz  ..  the junit test runs  without failure and xml reports are  generated  but the job failed because of thta error

Comment: @NicolasPepinster yes .. i have added gitlab ci file content in the question

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it ..  I made a mistake in my gitlab-ci.yml file

In the artifact:paths and artifact:reports:junit tags , I should add /*.xml in the path :

artifacts:
paths:
- $CI_PROJECT_DIR/build/junitreport/*.xml

reports:
junit: $CI_PROJECT_DIR/build/junitreport/*.xml
when: always